# How to make a line span all sections and sub sections in a unordered list?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, vuepress

I am currently working with Vuepress and am adding some styles to my documentation. One of which is a line that spans an entire section and then inner ones that will span the entire subsection as well, but the way in which I've written that code, with before and after, leaves a bit to be desired.

Is there anyway that I can write this before el to make it stretch the entire way down?

Similar to this:

[image]

**Vuepress sidebar**
[image]

**index.styl**

```
a{
  position: relative
}
.sidebar-sub-header .sidebar-link::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 12px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #525a63;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: "";
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
}
.sidebar-sub-header .sidebar-link::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 17px;
  width: 2px
  height: 100%
  background: #525a63;
}

.sidebar-group-items .sidebar-link::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 17px;
  width: 2px
  height: 100%
  background: #525a63;
}

.sidebar-sub-header .sidebar-link.active::after{
  background: #4771FA
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I have change my answer just create a straight line using `li`.

  ```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }

  .main {
    padding: 30px;
  }

  .list {
    position: relative;
  }

  .list>li.has-subList>ul {
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
  }

  .list li:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #525a63;
  }

  .list li>a {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .list a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: -2px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #525a63;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="main">
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">data 1</a></li>
      <li class="has-subList">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sublist data 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sublist data 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sublist data 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">data 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">data 3</a></li>
      <li class="has-subList">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sublist data 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">sublist data 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the comment!
I don't think I properly explained what I was looking for and will update the post.
Essentially I want to have a line drawn all the way down for each section/subsection. So not all one connected, but rather have the outer most reach all the way to the bottom and then the inner ones all do the same, but only in their respective level!

You did teach me some valuable css already though!

Comment: It would be great if you could share some image of graphical representation for expected output.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for just run my code again